# How do I use CKEditor 5?

Tags: 9

It has been told that Drupal 9 comes with CKEditor 5.

How do I use it?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal core will provide an upgrade path of switching from CKEditor 4 to 5 without data loss. You should be able to switch the editor from 4 to 5 in your text format with an action as simple as changing the editor and saving the text format.

Check for the updates provided in DrupalCon Portland in this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwDFCLaQVbY

Comment: is it possible to share the exact documentation provided by drupal, when I type `php c:\MyFiles\composer\composer.phar show -i | find "ckeditor"` I see `drupal/ckeditor                             1.0.1` I don't know how to use it

Comment: @DickensAS - I have added the video link by the company responsible for writing the CKEditor.

Comment: thanks for the help, I went inside `<mysite>/admin/modules` and enabled CkEditor 5 and went inside `<mysite>/admin/config/content/formats` and re configured, it started working